# How to reload elements on a page in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi All I have a an AJAX query as seen below:

```
function buttonCallback(obj){

        var id = $(obj).attr('id');

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/project/main/passid",
            data: { 'id': id  },
            success: function(msg){
                 $("#reloadtable").html("result reloaded successfully"); //? reload?
            }
         });
    }
```

the query successfully runs - I was hoping to reload a table I have created in html after the query runs - I took some code from another post but it doesn't seem to run - my table body tag is:

```
<tbody class = "tablereload">
```

I am entirely new to JS so I apologise if this question is stupid or incorrect - but I am hoping to reload the body of the table after the query has run - is this possible? or refreshing the whole page - without redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page `/project/main/passid` should return html like  (echo it if it is php page)

```
<tr>
  <td>.....</td>
</tr>
```

And changes to you Ajax call:

```
function buttonCallback(obj){

    var id = $(obj).attr('id');

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/project/main/passid",
        data: { 'id': id  },
        success: function(msg){
             $(".tablereload").html(msg); //? reload?
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have a ID selector and in the html you have a class for the tbody.

You can put the Id for the tbody

```
 <tbody id = "tablereload">
```

or change the script

```
 $(".reloadtable").html("result reloaded successfully");
```